# custom ribbon for ms access 2016

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have created a custom ribbon in access 2016, using xml codeing provided on this site from previous postings.
For the most part it works just fine except the "New", "Save As", and "Feedback" buttons are still visible , and functioning.
Does anyone know how to hide or disable these 3?
Heres the coding i'm using:

```
    <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
      <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
           <!-- Ribbon XML -->
      </ribbon>
      <backstage>
      <button idMso="FileSave" visible="false"/>
      <button idMso="SaveObjectAs" visible="false"/>
      <button idMso="FileSaveAsCurrentFileFormat" visible="false"/>
      <button idMso="FileOpen" visible="false"/>
      <button idMso="FileCloseDatabase" visible="false"/>
      <tab idMso ="TabInfo" visible="false"/>
      <tab idMso ="TabRecent" visible="false"/>
      <tab idMso ="TabNew" visible="false"/>
      <tab idMso ="TabPrint" visible="false"/>
      <tab idMso ="TabShare" visible="false"/>
      <tab idMso ="TabHelp" visible="false"/>
      <button idMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" visible="false"/>
      <button idMso="FileExit" visible="false"/>
     </backstage>
</customUI>
```

Comment: You can pretty much ignore the post, I found that if I just disable the "Allow Full Menus" option for the current database the problem is solved

Comment: Sorry, that didn't totally solve the issue. I changed the xml coding to allow "Print", so the user can have the "Print Preview" open on reports. I have vba to hide the ribbon when, and unhide when a report is opened. When I disable the "Allow Full Menus" some print preview options (Export to Excel) are gone.I really wanted those, but maybe I should well enough alone, unless some can help me with hiding the "New", "Save As", and "Feedback" options on the custom ribbon

Answer (score 1):

I dug around the internet and came up with this solution provided by rmk

```
    <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <backstage>
     <!-- Info -->
     <tab idMso ="TabInfo" visible="false"/> 
     <!-- New -->
     <tab idMso ="TabOfficeStart" visible="false"/> 
     <!-- Open -->
     <tab idMso="TabRecent" visible="false"/>
     <!-- Save -->
     <button idMso="FileSave" visible="false"/>
     <!-- Save As -->
     <tab idMso="TabSave" visible="false"/>
     <!-- Print -->
     <tab idMso ="TabPrint" visible="true"/>
     <!-- Close -->
     <button idMso="FileCloseDatabase" visible="false"/>
     <!-- Account -->
     <tab idMso="TabHelp" visible="false"/>
     <!-- Options -->
     <button idMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" visible="false"/>
    </backstage>
  </customUI>
```

It worked great, the only thing left is the "Send Feedback" option which I guess is a microsoft issue

Comment: You can select your own answer as the official answer and close this question out. You get points for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <tab idMso="TabRecent" visible="false"/> is this tag only hide the open button or its also disable the NEW Button .In my XML this tag making NEW Button Disable in office 365 version 2016.
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles across this. The "Feedback" tab can be hidden with this:

```
<tab idMso="TabOfficeFeedback" visible="false"/>
```

List with "all" can be found here:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers