# What is the idMso for the new Help tab in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, ribbon

As of last week, I am seeing a new Help tab in Microsoft Access 2016. I have designed a database with a custom ribbon that hides all of the core tabs, using only some custom tabs I have designed. I have searched through this website and Google but cannot find the idMso of the new tab so that I can hide it, too. It looks like the Office Fluent User Interface download has not been updated since January 2016, so does not contain information on this new tab.

Does anyone know the idMso of the new Help tab or have any suggestions for how I can figure it out? Thank you.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: New Help tab in Access]

Comment: What are you currently using? Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105660/custom-ribbon-for-ms-access-2016

Comment: It doesn't appear that the link has a solution for hiding the entire tab, though they did manage to hide some (not all) of the individual buttons. Affected Access is Office 365 Business version 1803 build 9126.2152.

Answer (score 4):

The idMso is "HelpTab"

To find a new idMso that is not in the "Office Fluent user interface", you can customize the ribbon (File -> Options) by hiding the control and export the customization, it's an XML file.

Comment: I have tried both TabHelp and HelpTab and neither hides the new tab. Unfortunately, the tab does not show up on my development machine, but does show up on the production machines using MS Access Runtime. There is no option in Runtime to export the XML file.